# My electron app size is 530mb . So, i unzip the asar file that i found it has node_modules folder which itself takes 300 mb how to remove it?

Tags: angular, electron, electron-packager

I just unzip the asar file . Please check below it has both compressed and uncompressed `node_modules` how to remove it. So that I can reduce my app size to 200 mb. Is there any way to reduce it from npm command or another solution?
[image]

I want to remove node_modules folder from asar file.

Comment: man you just need to deploy dist folder. Why are you copying entire codebase.

Answer (score 3):

[ModClean](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modclean) will help you reduce size of your npm app. It finds and removes unnecessary files and folders from your node_modules directory based on predefined and custom glob patterns.

Also gave a look at this [nice guide](https://medium.com/@tomi.trescak/reducing-size-of-npm-based-projects-1b02ebe32d61) and [this guide too](https://hackernoon.com/whats-really-wrong-with-node-modules-and-why-this-is-your-fault-8ac9fa893823) about reducing app size.

Comment: Is it much better than npm prune??

Answer (score 1):

This is mainly due to how you package your electron app, you could need some stuff from the node_modules so it assumes `dependencies` to be for production.

You should only deploy dist files for an electron app. And then exclude all development related dependencies like `webpack` to your `devDependency`. Since `prune` in electron packer is enabled by default it will not add those at all to your `.asar`.

Same applies to `Vue`, `React`, `Angular` or any other library that has been processed by webpack, if you make a dist folder anything besides electron should end up as `devDependency` except you really want it for production.

If you have native packages like `electron-edje-js` it cannot be called from the `.asar`, so you exclude it from being packed by putting it into your `devDependencies` and copy the necessary binary files to your resulting application.

Comment: actually asar file having whole angular app. how to deploy only dist folder in it?

Comment: When you call electron-packer you have to do it with `electron-packager ./dist` I assume you do it on the project root instead?

Comment: yes i was doing it without ./dist . Does the electron-edge plugin works if i take a build with ./dist

Comment: Not out of the box, your dist is only a build of your data files (.js / .jpg /. json / .txt) while electron-edge gives you a (.node) binary and (.dll) libraries. In our application we move them via a script into the build electron app at `<Project>/out/win-unpacked/resources/<OurDllsAndBinaries>` once the build is done.

Comment: But other projects for example slack have a folder named `<ElectronAppFolder>/Resources/asar-unpacked/node_modules/<DllsAndBinaries>` (node_modules is only there to group the files), so there is no standard way of naming things.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had made copies of the **dist** folder for reference. e.g. My directory was something like

```
- root
    |- dist
    |- dist-old
    |- dist-test
```

In the app.asar it included dist-old and dist-test. Seems electron-builder is greedy and will bundle anything it does not recognise into the app.

Comment: That's exactly what was happening for me, even while my `dist01`, `dist02, etc were under a `dust` folder... I removed them completely and my app is now "light" again !